# Telebot(Python): сверить сообщение юзера с правильным вариантом

Tags: python, бот, telebot

Суть: нужно, чтобы бот отправлял вопрос и ждал на него правильный ответ. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `if message.text == 'ваш текст':` `выполняемое действие`. Если же нужно ждать ответа от юзера - воспользуйтесь методом `register_next_step_handler`

Comment: вот если бы можно было передать аргумент функции в register_next_step_handler, было бы лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def math(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, '2 + 2 = ?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, twopluspwo)

def twopluspwo(message):
    if message.text == '4':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Yes')
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'No')
```

Подробнее в [step_examples](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)